# When marking a question as duplicate last comment get removed surprisingly

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I'm not sure if this is a **bug** or a *part of marking duplication function*, check out below screenshots to understood what I mean.

This was the review task which I was checking, https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4279826

This was the question link, [How to play sound in iOS app along with the music in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139904/how-to-play-sound-in-ios-app-along-with-the-music-in-background)

[image]

[image]

To reproduce this at your side,

1. Start reviewing for duplicate questions.
2. *If you find a question which is really meant to be duplicate* ***and which have at least one comment on it***.
3. Click on close button, it'll show you number of (already marked) duplicate marked by other reviewers.
4. *If you see 4 (already duplicate mark by other reviewers) then you can product this*
5. Open that question link in other tab for reference before marking it as duplicate.
6. Now mark that question as duplicate.
7. Now look other tab (which you opened in step no.5).
8. Pay attention on last comment made on that question, still you find it's there.
9. Refresh the page!
10. Boom! last comment get hidden! What? Why? Where? By whom?
11. This is not only happened to a single comment or possible duplicate recommendation comment. Its happening with any number of comments, what ever is last will get remove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected and normal behaviour.

The comment was inserted by the first user to cast the duplicate vote.

It gets removed when the last user casts their vote and the questions is closed as a duplicate as the information is now in the close notice at the top of the post.

There's no need for the comment to still exist.

Comment: You're right @ChrisF, I just checked for the other type of comments and its persist even after marked duplicate.