# Why is a moderator's tag red?

Tags: support, meta-tags

I asked a question today, [When marking a question as duplicate last comment get removed surprisingly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259908/when-marking-a-question-as-duplicate-last-comment-get-removed-surprisingly), User (he's a moderator) [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) edited it with a tag named [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Why is my tag is gray colored and his tag red?

[image]

- Are only moderators edited tags red?
- Why does a tag become red coloured?
- Do more colours of tags exist?

Comment: Those are moderator-only tags. You can't apply them to posts on Meta. Only mods can.

Comment: @Bart, thanks for the quick reply. Is there more no.of coloured tags available for moderators? Can a user like me (who's not a moderator) can ask a question with coloured tag?

Comment: Nope, you can't. And there are plenty. `[faq]` [community-ads] [featured] [status-*] See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most red tags are moderator status tags.  They all begin with status-* because they show the status of the question.  This allows moderators to know which questions:

- introduced a problem that is now solved [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- introduced no problem because the behavior is expected [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
- are not able to be reproduced [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) means your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is not going to be implemented.

There are many more, which you can find [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-*).  Only moderators are able to add these because these tags are used as a simple way for the site developers to sort through the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tags.

---

There are also others such as [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads), [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) as [Bart pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259913/why-a-tag-is-full-of-red-coloured/#comment39456_259914).

- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq): a collection of questions that are meant to represent how the site works
- [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads): a way for new ads to come into the site if they are positively voted on
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured): a way for moderators to provide special attention to a question and possibly move it to the Community Bulletin

Answer (score 7):

There are three classes of tag on site metas:

1. Regular tags, like this one: [tags](/questions/tagged/tags). Anyone can use them and they are only applied to posts when relevant.
2. Required tags, these are: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [support](/questions/tagged/support). At least one of these flags has to be present on all questions. Anyone can add them, but if you remove the last one you must add a different one in its place. They are distinguished by having a dark grey border.
3. Moderator only tags, like this one [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). They usually start with `status-` and are used to show the status (!) of the question, but there are others (like [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)). These can only be added or removed by a moderator or SE staff member (those with diamonds (♦) after their names).

Comment: And there are `[faq]`, [community-ads] and [featured]

Comment: @Bart - indeed. I forgot about those.