# Question possible duplicate marking behaviour?

Tags: discussion, support

A user asked a question, [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) after I asked a question (which already got two answers and I accepted one of them too.) It's here, [Why is a moderator's tag red?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259913/why-a-tag-is-full-of-red-coloured?noredirect=1#comment39466_259913).

I've seen that someone marking my question as duplicate of that question, which is asked after mine.

I am not sure, why this happening? If a question was asked after another question then how someone can mark it as duplicate?

Comment: Because Martijn Pieters decided to make a CW as a guide on using meta.Your question is *just* about tags which is covered in that post. Besides, the time factor is not all that is considered in marking one as a target over the other. It depends on the information in the Q and A and which would be more helpful for users searching. Now people can find everything (?) in one place since many don't seem to use the help sections on these sites.

Comment: When we have a faq item for something, it's ideal to close anything answered by it as duplicate. This way the data is stored in one central place, easy to search and find - more dupes, more keywords to search. :)

Comment: I ported the [How does Meta FAQ page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work) exactly to address your question in a canonical location, that's what FAQ posts are for. We regularly close posts as duplicates of newer posts when those newer posts cover the subject better or are easier to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When two questions cover the same ground eg "What does error 12345 mean while compiling?" in a particular language, the choice of which to keep as the "master" question and which to mark as a duplicate of it is never based on when the questions were asked, but on which has the better set of answers. (Sometimes, they both have answers; when that happens you can flag the closed one and ask to have its answers merged into the open one.)

But it sometimes happens that a question is a duplicate of a **subset** of another question. For example someone asks "what are the costs of the various public transit options between A and B?" and the answers include bus, train, and ferry costs, then someone asks "what is the cost of the bus between A and B?" - you can close the specific question as a dupe of the general, but not vice versa.

If you feel that your specific question is asking something that is **not covered** in the more general question, then you need to [edit your question to make that clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/147247), and include a link to the more general question. If you actually know the answer, then it makes sense to put that answer in the more general question to help everyone. None of this logic has anything to do with when the questions were asked.

Answer (score 3):

As one of the people who voted your question as a duplicate;

It is.

Reverse the situation: Do you think [Martijns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) question is a good duplicate of [your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259913/why-a-tag-is-full-of-red-coloured?noredirect=1#comment39466_259913)?

I think we can agree that your question(or an answer to it) is already covered by How does Meta Stack Overlow work?