# Can we have a special color for tags describing the language used in the post?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In Meta site we have 3 types of tag: (as can see in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259914/6487675) post)

1. Regular tag - in grey
2. Moderator tags - which are red
3. Require tags - which has darker grey color

In SO we don't have those kind of tags but I find the tag coloring helps me in Meta. Can we take the concept of having special tags have special color (or just rendered differently) to have them noticed faster?

Can we decide, for example, **to have language specific tags to be rendered differently**?

I am not claiming each post should have a language tag, just **if** the post has one it would be colored, for example, in red. If there is more than one language tag they are all have the special renderer. The decision for which tag will be defined as language-related can be done by moderators.

I suggest the language tags to be colored differently as most questions have at least one language tag and it is an important tag for most of the questions as the OP is sharing code in that language.

I search for this kind of color use on [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281741/6487675) and found we do use color for a lot of thing (as it is helps) - so I believe we can also use color in knowing the language of the post faster and easier.

Comment: We would need to change tags to add a flag indicating whether it's a language tag. Currently nothing differentiates a "language tag" from any other tag. You could guess by looking at those that have a formatting hint applied to them, but that's not accurate, as many tags use another language's format and many languages have no format.

Comment: Agreed - that the core of my suggestion - have some tags mark/flag as language (regardless the hint if exist)

Comment: I've updated the text a bit to make it easier (for me) to understand. You may want to consider removing references to making the tags red. The color red has specific cultural meanings that should be considered, and your post might be better served by just asking that the tags be rendered differently from others.

Answer (score 2):

Many things have multiple languages:

- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
- [many many others](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/24/making-sense-of-the-metadata-clustering-4000-stack-overflow-tags-with-bigquery-k-means)

How would you pick which tag(s) to highlight?

Comment: There is nothing wrong (in my option) for marking all languages tags on red - 1 post can have 3 red tag - it still fine.