# Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, deleted-comments

I believe there is a auto-magical process that removes all comments that refer to "duplicate" question when "closed as duplicate" is chosen (existence for auto-generated comments covered in [comment removed when marked as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259908/when-marking-a-question-as-duplicate-last-comment-get-removed-surprisingly) ).

Is it possible to tweak the script so comments written by hand are not auto-removed in such case?

I.e. I have comment along the lines "not a duplicate of *Link_To_Duplicate* because of some reason" and indeed question was closed as duplicate soon with my comment disappearing ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669031/how-to-safely-access-windows-form-components-cross-threads-in-c?noredirect=1#25669031) ). According to comments automatic deletion definitely happening for comments that are *related* to potential duplicate.

Note: if the comments to linked question where manually deleted by someone I'd like to know the reason and better way to provide such comment (will reword question in this case).

**Question/request:** what format one should use for comments about potential duplicate so such comments will not be matched by auto-delete script.

Comment: The software is only supposed to delete comments of the form "Duplicate of [matching link to dup close]".  It might be matching `*duplicate*` (i.e. wildcards) too aggressively.

Comment: @RobertHarvey would you mind checking if I indeed had comment I claim I did :) on that question (not 100% sure if it is visible even to moderator in some sort of history). I'm reasonably sure I added such comment but after your remark I'm not so sure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am pretty sure that is not what is happening.  I have seen many comments with links to the duplicate deleted when closed.

Comment: This is indeed a problem.  There are a few cases where I intentionally did not use the hammer to avoid deleting a good comment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I undeleted the comment.  It appears to follow the exact pattern for comments that are summarily deleted when a question gets closed as duplicate.  The software doesn't know the difference between a system-generated comment and a hand-written comment, if your hand-written comment looks exactly like the system-generated one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - hmm I thought there was another one - I actually initially thought this is dup and closed it... There is a good chance that I did not add one, but it seem other people observe similar behavior.

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414)

Comment: I've commented on this before.  It bit me for the first time on TeX.SE where I asked about it on their meta, [why was “possible duplicate” comment with additional information deleted?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3786/29288).

Comment: Rather than requesting "what format one should use for comments about potential duplicate so such comments will not be matched by auto-delete script," could this request be "don't delete these comments"?  As I've [commented elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified#comment778165_141414) there's evidence that people *do* read those comments, and miss the duplicate links in the banners.  Removing the comments makes it harder to find not just the "extra" information, but the **vital** stuff, too.

Comment: If the sytem chooses candidate comments for deletion by comparing it with the default system generated message as @RobertHarvey says, I think system should have marked system entered comments with an `autogenerated` flag. wouldn't the process be efficient? Comparing a boolean/int is always faster than string compare or regex.

Comment: @Krumia Do remember that those auto-generated comments can still be edited.  it's not just a matter of checking whether it's autogenerated, but whether it's autogenerated and not subsequently edited.  I'll often VTC as a duplicate, but edit the comment just a little bit.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Well I did not consider that. But on a subsequent edit it will be a matter of clearing the flag. Voter editing the autogenerated comment means that it should not be removed.

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't base the script on whether the comment was made automatically or by hand, it should only decide based on the content of the comment.

**Suggestion:** Automatically delete comments of the form `^(\S*\s+)?duplicate of [any title text](any link that resolves to the dupe)(\s*\S)?$` when a question is closed with duplicate votes.

Notes:

- the expression is anchored, i.e. don't delete when only a part of the comment matches it.
- the `(\S*\s+)?` at the begin allows for an optional word such as "possible", "exact" or "obvious".
- the `(\s*\S)?` at the end allows for an optional punctuation.

The rationale is to delete handwritten-comments that resemble the automatic message, but not to catch anything else, including substantially edited automatic comments.

Comment: This is mostly OK, *except* that (and it may be surprising), people *miss* the banner that mentions the duplicate, and read the comments to find out what the duplicate is.  See [my earlier comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified#comment778165_141414).   If you delete the comment that leads to the actual dupe, then the other possible dupes that didn't get as much support may seem more relevant than the *actual* dupe.

Comment: You're right that the visibility of the banner should be improved (I once had an OP who asked what the duplicate was, he only saw the "closed" notice - and no dupe comment is generated by the hammer). However I think that comments for *all* the possible duplicates from the "has already an answer" box can (should) be deleted.

Comment: I disagree. I often comment or edit the auto-generated comment to represent something like _"This is a duplicate of [duplicate], you're doing X while you should be doing Y"_. Such comments should simply not be deleted.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, as soon as the comment is touched and contains additional information, it should not be deleted.

Comment: Oops, I missed the end anchor. You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 11):

Why delete such comments at all? I suppose after the first three comments, no one will actually keep commenting that. And the overhead created from <= 3 comments per duplicate is not that big, is it?

Comment: What's the point of having a whole bunch of "duplicate" comments if the question is already closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Makoto (and FooBar, too) I don't think that subsequent close-as-duplicate votes (for the same duplicate) generate additional comments.  Comments about other possible duplicates are relevant precisely because they're other possible duplicates.

Comment: Yet those other duplicates (if submitted as dupe) are listed at the top of the question.  No one wants to sift through a list of comments to find duplicates.

Comment: @Makoto: The point is that you don't lose valuable comments. No matter how complicated the regex, you can always lose good information. This is pretty much, given the small cost of few duplicate comments.

Comment: @Makoto: No, not necessarily. Some people aren't quite sure and write "possible duplicate" and _mean_ "possible" duplicate, but don't VTC because they aren't sure. When other people come storming in and close the question as a duplicate of something else, that original commenter's theory — which may turn out to be pointing out a much _better_ duplicate — is silently lost forever. And for what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It isn’t lost, just added to the banner.

Comment: @minitech Isn't it just the comments from the close votes that are added to the banner?  If someone just writes a comment "Possible duplicate of QQQQ." but doesn't close vote, then QQQQ won't get added to the banner, but the comment can still be deleted, no?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Comments that link to things that aren’t added to the banner aren’t deleted, as far as I know. If they are, that’s more than a little silly.

Comment: @minitech Comments that *link to things that **aren't** added* to the banner, or comments that ***don't** link to things that **are** added* to the banner? I.e., what happens if Q is closed as a dupe of A, so A appears in the banner, but someone left a comment saying "This is probably a dupe of A or B."  If that comment gets deleted because it links to A, then we lose the information about B.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I agree with that (and the request in general) but is Lightness Races in Orbit’s comment about that case?

Comment: LRiO's comment would be included in a case like that, I think.  Since most of us don't have knowledge of what comments actually get auto-deleted, it's really tough to evaluate what problems might exist and what improvements could be made.

Comment: @minitech: Yes. As I said in my first comment, "but don't VTC because they aren't sure". The topic of this entire Q&A is hand-written comments regarding duplicateness, as distinct from auto-generated comments resulting from VTC.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Note that this only applies in the case of a comment that links to both an accepted duplicate and another duplicate that didn’t have a vote, and is what I was asking whether you were asking about.

Comment: @minitech: That's interesting then and suggests that the premise of this question/request is flawed. Perhaps you could write this in an answer to clarify the current mechanism.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn’t know it was under question. If it is, I’m probably wrong. But it would be very unusual for unrelated comments that simply contain links to be deleted when a question is closed as a duplicate of another.

Comment: @minitech: Right, hence this post on Meta which is asking for that "feature" to be removed! And if it's _not_ the case then as I say the premise is flawed and this could be addressed in an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I thought the question was about comments containing links to a question that ended up in the duplicate banner, but also contained other useful information (edited from the automatic comment or not).