# possible-duplicate comment removed even if not mentioned in the close reason

Tags: support, bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26167826/1048572) (which is about precision limits of floating point literals) was closed very incorrectly as a duplicate of [this other question about truncating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript) (should I just hammer it open with my JavaScript Mjölnir, or possibly inform a moderator so that the voters can be treated adequately?).

However, the actual problem is that my comment vanished. It was something like

```
possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812096/1048572 or
https://stackoverflow.com/q/8663298/1048572 (about ints, but the same problem)
or https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108729/1048572 for a solution
```

Oddily, the links are still present in the *Linked* box in the sidebar. **Why was this comment removed?**

I would have understood this to be a side effect of [Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270643/1048572), but only if the duplicate question *that was voted for* would have been actually *linked in my comment*.

Comment: See the MSE question listed in the comments.

Comment: @Ben: Which one do you mean?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414/179419; it's been like this for a while...

Comment: Oh, you're right, I hadn't followed all the links deeply. I didn't knew it was really **that bad**.