# Merge 'possible duplicate' comments and votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

I recently came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229238/check-if-string-contain-regex-pattern-php) which had the following comments:

[image]

Both links in the comments pointed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563658/php-check-file-extension) question.

Can we make it so that if the 'Possible duplicate' is the same as one which has already been suggested, it just up-votes the original one rather than adding more "noise" to the question by adding another comment?

---

**Edit #1**

**Note:** As [@duplode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) quite rightly [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367526/merge-possible-duplicate-comments-and-votes?noredirect=1#comment586660_367526), one user is below the required reputation to VTC. As such, it might have been a flag. In which case, this changed my original request to merge VTC and flagged duplicates where they point to the same original question.

---

**Edit #2**

As [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367526/merge-possible-duplicate-comments-and-votes?noredirect=1#comment587488_367526) by [@Machavity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity) in his comment, that once he duped the question, both comments were removed and that would only occur if it was a auto generated system comment, in which case this is definitely a bug.

Comment: Normally, that's what it does. One of the comments may have been posted manually.

Comment: The author of the first comment doesn't have 3k rep. Could it be that comments from flags don't merge with those from close votes?

Comment: @duplode could very likely be so. Good spot.

Comment: @duplode, actually whenever I've VTC'ed a question that was already flagged by a user with rep < 3k, it never generated a comment; but, upvoted the existing comment. So, in this case it looks one of the comments was manually added (as Cerbrus said).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I guessed wrongly, then. (I had had a quick look but couldn't find a Meta question about it to confirm what I was saying.)

Comment: note that a manual comment like this isn't trivial to create.

Comment: There might be some additional stuff going on with close-votes vs. close-flags. Yesterday, I noticed that the duplicate question (in the duplicate pane of the close-vote dialog) displayed a 6 in the badge indicating that there were 6 votes for that question as a duplicate. However, the main pane of the close dialog only showed 4 votes in the "duplicate" badge (as was the count after "close" on the question).

Comment: Although as Fabre said, it's slightly complicated to make a manual comment, what I find more likely is that it was created by a user script.

Comment: I want to share personal anecdote that might be related: when I first started contributing to Stack Overflow, I didn't know that these comments were automatically created and just thought it was an agreed-upon way to tell the OP that a solution already exists. So I distinctly remember manually creating a comment like this one or two times before I found out how they are really created. So maybe that is what happened here?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It can be if users have no userscripts. It's possible that one of the users had a user script that automatically replaces links to SO questions with the question title, I have such a userscript called `SE Comment Link Helper`.

Comment: I hammered it and, interestingly, both comments were deleted. Not sure if that means anything

Comment: @Machavity IIRC, it only deletes the comments if they are done through the system's' automatic comment maker. In which case, my post stands. Thanks for the hammering.

Comment: About *edit 2*, this is not a bug. Comments by a mod: [*The software is only supposed to delete comments of the form Duplicate of "matching link to dup close"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate#comment90003_270643); and [*The software doesn't know the difference between a system-generated comment and a hand-written comment.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate#comment90046_270643)

Answer (score 5):

So... One of those comments was just typed in. The author didn't flag or vote, they just found the duplicate and typed out the "Possible duplicate of..." comment.

If it was the first comment, then the system wouldn't have recognized it as being associated with a duplicate flag or vote, and would've created a new one.

If it was the second comment, then the system would've *already* created a flag-associated comment by the time it was posted.

If this seems overly restrictive... It kinda is. OTOH, the alternative requires matching on the comment text, which has at least as many ways to fail.

Folks just typing in "possible duplicate" comments instead of voting or flagging happens on average about 14 times a day.

Comment: Matching on the comment text(case insensitive and ignoring white space differences) will be good to avoid questions like “comment is a possible duplicate of the preceding one.” https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010144/convert-variable-to-type-only-known-at-run-time#comment97906727_4010144