# Do high privilege users have rights to delete comments?

Tags: support, comments, privileges, deleted-comments

I have commented on question with a link as it appears to be the duplicate of a previous asked question. After a few moments I got back to the question where I commented. A user with 50K reputation marked it as a duplicate and my comment is no longer there. So my question is: do high privilege users have rights to delete comments?

Comment: They are deleted automatically IIRC.

Comment: [Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate)

Comment: Strictly speaking every [high privileged (15+ rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) user have rights to delete comments via flagging (may not be singlehanded like automatic removal of "duplicate of" or flat out offensive comments, but still sort of delete)

Answer (score 19):

No, [only ♦ moderators have that privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/295232), though sometimes one comment flag by a regular user can remove a comment. This is not one of those cases, though.

Your comment was *automatically* removed by the system; once the question is marked as a duplicate, the system sees your comment isn't necessary anymore (because the close banner makes it obsolete). Therefore, it will remove the comment.

(One *could* consider this a privilege, but it's not tied to reputation: it's the [gold tag badge that matters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/4751173). And if 5 regular users close a question as a duplicate, the comment is removed too.)

Comment: If a question is closed as a duplicate, comments that link to the same duplicate target are removed. (I'm not sure if there's anything clever behind it to preserve possibly valuable comments, or if it just removed all of'm that contain that link)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes one comment flag can removed the comment if it matches a regex Shog has. A comment is also deleted when it receives 3+(score/3) flags (AFAIK).

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you've flagged a question as a duplicate, and then edited the system-generated comment to add additional information.

Simply don't do the latter. Add a new comment. **Any comment linking to the duplicate target can and will be automatically deleted when a question gets closed as a duplicate.**

It shouldn't be deleted if you edited the comment, but the code associated with this removal mechanism has been broken so many times that you should simply not edit "possible duplicate of ..." comments, but simply add a new comment if you want to say more than that.

See also:

- [Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate)
- [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified).

According to that last question and its accepted answer from last January, this should be fixed. Again. But it probably isn't.

Comment: Sir... you mean to say that if a user marked as duplicate as the link I provide So it will remove the comment automatically as the link are same

Comment: Yes, that's the intended usage of those auto-generated "possible duplicate of ..." comments.

Comment: @wings it looks like you literally typed the comment "possible duplicate of" - I'd suggest in future, you use the "flag as dupe" option, that way - it'll create the comment for you, and push the post into the Close Vote queue for others to review. Just posting a comment doesn't actually do anything except create a comment.

Comment: Yes Sir I typed like that....Ok Sir will keep in mind next time

Comment: @Jon Clements And one more thing Sir is this really a bad question because I am getting only downvotes

Comment: @wings nope - it's not bad... it's been asked many times before, but sometimes it's not easy to find things when searching - I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: @wings there's somewhat less need to worry about downvotes here on meta though as they don't affect your reputation.

Comment: @RobertLongson....Sir its not about reputation If I get downvotes it discourage me to ask more questions :(

Comment: @wings You may wish to cease assuming everyone is a Sir. We're not *that* formal here anyway, you can just say what you mean, no honorifics necessary or desired.

Comment: @wings if you really need to use formal tone - all encompassing version like "Dear Sirs and Dames". Also I'd recommend checking (and maybe asking) on https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=sir to pick the best variant.