# How to retrieve the user who marked a question as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, profile-page, deleted-comments, automatic-comments

I had a question which was (correctly) marked as duplicate by someone. I received a note in the comments along the lines "possible duplicate of ...".

I confirmed the that the question is indeed a duplicated and it was marked as duplicate by "Community".

The comment was removed ([as designed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259908/when-marking-a-question-as-duplicate-last-comment-get-removed-surprisingly)).

**Is there a way to retrieve the user who initially marked it as duplicate?** (his username was in the comment but I forgot to open his/her profile before confirming the dupe)

Comment: They should appear as the other (or the first, if there is more than one) user name in the closure banner.

Comment: @duplode In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567398/how-to-declare-and-initialize-a-global-variable-in-one-go), it was a duplicate suggestion/flag (without a vote) and Community was the only vote.

Comment: @duplode Not if was a dupe flag (instead of a duple close vote).

Comment: @Undo and yivi : Oh, I see. Then I suppose there is no way (at least, not one that doesn't involve asking a mod), as flag ownership isn't public information, right?

Comment: @duplode: it is not secret information either (in that case) as the username was visible in the comment

Comment: @WoJ Yup, it isn't secret -- the unavailability of this information to regular users post-closure would be merely a side effect.

Comment: Not sure if it will show in the post's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50567398/timeline) or not once the comment is deleted... was Mark the person who initially voted/flagged as a dupe?

Comment: @TylerH: It does not show on the timeline (at least for me). And I do not know who was the one who flagged/voted -- actually I wanted to see his/her profile to check his/her other answers (I find that usually when someone manages to find a dupe, he is usually knowledgeable about the subject and can have interesting answers)

Comment: @WoJ Gotcha. I switched out the tag from [meta-tag:discussion] to [meta-tag:support] since you are asking for assistance with a part of the SO site/system.

Comment: If the question Undo linked is the one you're curious about, it looks like it was [ollien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103734/ollien) who flagged. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPxuP.png