# Why does a comment linking to a duplicate does not get auto-deleted after a question has been closed as a duplicate?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I just closed [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59240083/how-to-convert-jsx-to-html?noredirect=1) to be a duplicate of another, however the auto-comment of the user proposing the duplicate is still there... Is this intentional?

[image]

The automatic comment was created by the system on behalf of the user at the same time as the flag:

[image]

I mean, it is supposed to be [auto-deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259908/when-marking-a-question-as-duplicate-last-comment-get-removed-surprisingly), right?

Comment: Yep, I've seen that happen a few times too

Comment: @certainPerformance I suspect it happens when people without the voting privilege flag for a duplicate ...

Comment: @samuelLiew but ... that comment was still added automatically right? I saw this multiple times already and I don't think that all these users wrote exactly the same comment manually ... And if it was added automatically, I assume it should also be removed automatically ...

Comment: IIRC, before the change, those who flagged to close without VTC privileges still had an auto-comment posted, and that auto-comment gets upvoted when others VTC too, and removed if the closure succeeds. But now, the auto-comment isn't being removed in some situations.

Comment: OH? It seems that the automated comment **text** was changed?!

Comment: @samuelLiew Oh, right, welcome back :) (was part of the new cv ui).

Comment: Can confirm; I've seen the auto-comment fail to be auto-deleted on multiple occasions. This has been [reported as a bug on the announcement on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339888#339888), and marked [status-review] by the developer.