# Closing as a dupe does not necessarily clear auto-comments

Tags: bug

I recently found several examples of auto-comments that were not removed by the question being marked as a duplicate.

Here's an example on Meta:
[image]

[image]

And here's a main-site example:

[image]

[image]

In both cases, I do notice that the person who cast the flag that resulted in the auto-comment had less than 3K rep, so they were not listed in the list of close voters. Also, the questions were ultimately closed as duplicates of the question that the <3k user proposed (in the first case, because 5 community members voted to close it as a dupe, and in the second case because someone with Mjolnir hammered it).

Normally, closing a question as a dupe of the proposed target would remove the auto-comment, but in these cases it didn't happen.

Is this a defect?

(Another case is when someone with less than 3k rep proposes a duplicate that's different than what the 3k users voted for; that's a separate question, though.)

Comment: Related: [Why does a comment linking to a duplicate does not get auto-deleted after a question has been closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391975/11682469) (also on MSE, see [Cody's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391975/why-does-a-comment-linking-to-a-duplicate-does-not-get-auto-deleted-after-a-ques#comment744190_391975))

Comment: If this gets fixed and then the comment also gets deleted when it's edited, I'm gonna be mad.